# Чем отличаются правила обособления согласованных и несогласованных определений?

Tags: пунктуация

Если обособление согласованных определений — тема непростая, то обособление несогласованных определений — тема непредсказуемая. Всё дело в том, что наши правила всегда похожи на инструкции, а в особо трудных случаях они превращаются в пошаговые инструкции, пользоваться которыми весьма затруднительно.

И в то же время решить вопрос об обособлении несогласованных определений можно быстро и без правил-инструкций, если пользоваться не конкретными правилами, а общей идеей, одновременно отслеживая  влияние различных факторов. Обоснованность же обособления легко проверить с помощью интонации.

Но для успешного "идейного" решения задачи надо ответить, как мне кажется, на поставленный вопрос: в чем сходство и в чем различие несогласованных и согласованных определений (при решении вопроса об их обособлении)?

Comment: Вера, тема непредсказуемая - обособление согласованных определений - или несогласованных определений? У вас опечатка.

Comment: Кстати, по поводу интонаций. Принцип русской пунктуации не интонационный, там где присутствует интонация обособления - может и не быть обособления и наоборот.

Comment: Серж, речь идет о несогласованных определениях, и думаю, что при обособлении всегда делается ПАУЗА между определяемым существительным и падежной формой несогласованного определения.  Вы можете привести примеры, где нет соответствия между паузой и запятой?

Comment: Вера, пройдитесь по ссылке.

Comment: Да, я понял, что речь идет о несогласованных определения. Просто у вас в тексте опечатка, я поэтому написал.

Comment: А почему нельзя ответить на этот вопрос? Правила не знаем или сравнить не можем? В классических правилах не упоминается интонация, поэтому можно обойтись без этой темы. Ну хотя бы такой вопрос: есть принципиальное различие или нет? На него можно ответить двумя предложениями.